# Send SPAlert to specific user who doesn't subscribe that list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, alert

How to generate SPAlert from some list to specific user with c# who doesn't subscribe that list? User cannot be added to list subscribers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have written your own implementation of OnNotification() you can send the email to whomever you would like. 
[Alert customization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18253/alert-customization/49296#49296)

It is possible to send a user an alert without having them be a subscriber, but it is a poor workaround to a better design alternative of empowering the user to control their own alerts.

Here are the properties of an alert. The SPAlert item is a store of a few specific properties and then a reference to 3 other records solving the many:many:many problem by turning them into one:many. See the starred items below:

```
    Title             : Tasks
    AlertTemplateName : SPAlertTemplateType.Tasks.Ext
  * AlertTemplate     : SPAlertTemplate Name=SPAlertTemplateType.Tasks.Ext
    Filter            :
    Properties        : {mobileurl, filterindex, siteurl, eventtypeindex...}
    ID                : f908d7a0-cd2a-4257-a6fb-61c3e31a0b36
  * ListID            : 50e97c9d-57f6-4440-91bc-9d4c23b97147
    MatchId           :
    ItemID            :
    ListUrl           : Lists/Tasks
    List              : Tasks
    Item              :
    AlwaysNotify      : False
    DeliveryChannels  : Email
    AlertType         : List
    EventType         : All
    EventTypeBitmask  : -1
    AlertFrequency    : Daily
    AlertTime         : 10/24/2012 12:30:24 PM
    Status            : On
    User              : NotMyCompany\ghangas
  * UserId            : 1
    DynamicRecipient  :
```

The whole basis for the alerts system is to match up a list : alert template : Site Collection User. Your question asks if you can make a stool with only 2 legs. Naturally, the answer is yes, well kind of... You could make one with your service account as a user and catch that in your event receiver and then replace the email address

```
    if (alertHandler.headers["to"] == "ServiceAccountAsAStandInForAnEndUser@NotMyCompany.com")
    {
         alertHandler.headers["to"] = "ILoveSpam@NotMyCompany.com"
    }

    SPUtility.SendEmail(web, alertHandler.headers, alertHandler.body);
```

I would look at the requirements closely and see if this is a code solution to a people problem and consider drawing the line between people and code in a different place.

Comment: Hey it is cool! I will add some dumb domain user and set subscription to the list and I will extend my cyrrent OnNotification method! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint alerts do not have anything that would allow this.  However, you could do this via [SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx) as long as you don't mind the format of the message being a little bit different than a standard alert

Comment: In my requirements customized alert template should be used which is used for standard alert procedure (format of message mertters).

Comment: If you *must* use the Alert Template then you are going to be getting familiar with implementing your own IAlertNotifyHandler.  Check out this for more details : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx